# Database connection in parent constructor not working in child method

Tags: php, sql

I have a parent class page, and in it I have a constructor that connects to the database successfully. Here is the code for that:

```
//establish database connection
function __construct() {
    require('db_conn.php');

    $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
}
```

I want to be able to access the database in the subclass pages- for example the register page class.

I have a function login() in that register subclass that needs to access the database connection variable. Here is the code for that:

```
private function Register() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        //check data is valid i.e. not in database already

        $query = mysqli_query($this->conn,'SELECT * FROM users');
        if (mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "That email or username already exists!";
        } else {
            //store data
          }
```

The variable is being detected but seems to not hold a connection, which is strange because I've tried testing it with mysqli_ping() in the same function and it returned true.

If i require the db connection inside the function the query works.

This is my first time using OOP, could be I've missed something straightforward. any help would be great. thanks

I'm aware the queries are wrong- I just wanted to simplify them for the sake of debugging

1. List item

Comment: Please show both class definitions fully, as what you show is not enough to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and most obvious issue is that you dont seem to have selected the database you want to use. Remember MySQL manages multiple database.

Note parameter 4 of the mysqli class instantiation should contain a database name

```
new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

whereas yours does not

```
$this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,'MISSING DATABASE NAME');
```

> Can I suggest that while developing you add these lines to the top of all your scripts so that you see any errors in the browser.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: wow, it appears I still make stupid mistakes even after months. Thanks, will take a look at that code you suggested too.